# Forum for discussing application concept and application design

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

In my case I'm designing a rating system and want to discuss the benefit of using a 5-star system vs a binary up/down-vote - and might want to delve into technical aspects such as database representation, algorithms etc. Or I might wish to discuss things such as "gamification" concepts and how to incorporate them into my application, e.g. issues relating to application design. I haven't found any forum for these kinds of questions - is there such a site out there? I ask here because I'm guessing people here are most likely to be aware of such a site if it exist.

Also, it would be nice if such a stack-overflow site related to application design :).

Comment: Stack Exchange sites are not forums, and discussions are not their goal - they are Q&A sites. You need a traditional forum, or a chat room for that.

Comment: I see the point that stack exchange site isn't suited for discussions. That said there might still be room for a Q&A site related to application design - not for discussions, just questions and answers. Questions such as "Which framework is best for Y", "Benefits of X vs Y", that etc. broad questions get broad answers and there is no need to discuss - if you need to inquire further you ask more specific questions.

Comment: @Pking Such questions would not be allowed either, per the fact that they are shopping questions.. asking for lists, etc..  such a question type is entirely subjective.  Eg, there is no answer.

Comment: [Relevant link in that(^) regard](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: Illegal question or not, I still see an issue where people turn to stackoverflow for answers for these questions. Do a search for "best mvc framework" or "entity framework vs nhibernate" and you will find questions to stackoverflow. Soft questions, subjective answers, no discussions, yet people find them valuable enough to push them to the top in google page ranking.

Comment: While I agree they may be valuable, that does not mean they should be allowed; as noted, the SE network is about providing a Q&A site.  Subjective questions are pretty much unanswerable, given their nature.

Comment: Think of the typical question a beginner programmer might have: "what programming language should I start with". Do question like these have their place on a Q&A site? I'd say yes (not necessarily stackoverflow). And I do think there are clear objective answers to such subjective and vague questions, such as: "First you need to find out if you want X, Y or Z. Here are suggestions what to look into: E, F or G - the most popular choices on the market right now. G is deemed easy for beginners because of F and might be a good place to start.".

Comment: @Pking I'd say no; everyone has their own opinion, and there is no 'right' answer.  As the old close reason stated; such questions are likely to solicit debate/extended discussion, which is not the purpose of SE.

Comment: I well never understand why people confuse Google ranking with usefulness, on-topicness, or anything else except... google ranking.

Comment: You'd think people would get frustrated if google didn't give them pages that where somewhat useful/on-topic?

Comment: I don't get the concept that `subjective` is bad on SE sites. Often, `subjective` is a best choice based upon a set of choices. Seems like a very legitimate use of a question and answer site. If `subjectivity` were taken out of answers, many would be significantly less valuable.

Comment: @timpone "subjective" is not one of our current closing reasons, largely due to misunderstandings regarding what it meant. It hasn't been for a while now.

Comment: Huh? That there exists a result on Google has *nothing* at all to do with whether that content is appropriate for Stack Overflow. Google does not judge whether content it finds or links to is on topic in the target site. How could they?

Answer (score 2):

Discuss? No, not on stack exchange.

Get good quality knowledge-based answers to specific, detailed questions about those issues? Yes, stack exchange is excellent.

You can ask about user experience questions on https://ux.stackexchange.com/ but make sure you first read [what's on topic there](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Don't ask for opinions or discussion, give facts about what you're tryng to achieve and the options you were considering, and ask what you should take into account. Read highly upvoted questions for what goes down well on that site.

I imagine it's not the first time someone's wondered about voting systems, so have a thorough search for previous questions about that and read carefully. Your question will go down better if you show you've taking that on board and explain in what way your situation differs and what further information would help you.

For how to achieve it, Stack Overflow is fine, but don't ask for library recommendations, describe clearly what you're trying to achieve and what you've tried so far. On SO, it's particularly important to avoid asking "What's the best..." questions, and to demonstrate that you have a reasonable understanding of what you're doing.

Just don't expect a debate, ask in the most factual way you can.

Comment: Posed a more specific question about the topic of broad questions and discussions here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189770/broad-questions-not-deemed-fit-for-qa-format IMO if a question sparks debate and discussions (as can with any question factual or not) I don't think the question itself is the problem, its the people debating/discussing.

Comment: Instead of convincing people to redesign stackechange's principles which have evolved over years and are applied by a community of thousands of people to fit your questions, surely it would be simpler and more efficient to redesign your questions to fit stack exchange.

Comment: That would be kinda like pushing a square peg in a round hole, I think broad design questions has their place.. It's pretty clear that stack-exchange isn't the place for them judging by the responses I get.. it seems to violate all kinds of principles :).

Comment: Have you visited ux.stackexchange.com yet? You really really should. It feels very different over there, and less hard-edged. As I understand it, design questions are on topic there. Have a look round. Read [Good subjective, bad subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) too. SO itself has a zero tolerance of subjectivity, but some other sites can cope with broader questions. None of them want conclusion-free discussion and debate, but some of them manage to deal with topics that are far less mathematical.

Comment: @Pking Sorry I forgot to @-notify you in thaat comment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, seems like a more suitable place for design questions.