# Relaxation of rules for the sites and other suggestions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, moderation, off-topic

I would like to request relaxing of moderation rules to some extent, at least for new users, so that it will help new users like me get answers to their questions. It will also enable us to learn more about the sites and understand the rules on our own.

The forums I've seen, allow opinion and discussion unlike these Q&A sites.
There can be a separate Stack Exchange site which can integrate all topics. It can be a site for many kinds of 'off topic' questions just like a forum, rather than a boring Q&A site. It can also have moderators from various fields to keep an eye on it, based on the tags.
It is difficult for everyone to find the best place to ask their questions on their own.

I feel these 'strict' rules keep the sites running in the long run and make moderation much easier. If the question is from a new user, that's it! It's 'on hold' with the reason as 'off topic' or 'too broad' or something else. I don't think those with good reputation ever end up with a question being put on hold!

It should not be a condition that the user should know at least something about what he wishes to ask. Questions are asked in forums and Q&A sites basically to simplify the work to be done.
If a person can search using search engines, all day long, to find an answer, then there would be no need for forums and Q&A sites at all!!

Some more suggestions:

- Questions and answers can have gold badges for most number of votes
  and most number of moderator votes and all gold badge questions can
  be grouped together.
- The moderators can also regularly keep posting updates and
  information related to their field which should be easily accessible
  to everyone.

If these things are reviewed then it would be of great help to many users and other than that these groups of sites have an excellent power in shaping individuals and those who work.
I expect positive opinion from moderators and site administrators in this regard.

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a Forum.

Comment: Then what else is it?
I meant the individual websites of Stack Exchange.

Comment: A bunch of Q&A sites.

Comment: Why would we create a site for precisely all the content we've deemed not a good fit for sites within the network?

Comment: *"and other suggestions"* -- please always limit to one question. Thanks.

Comment: _"I don't think those with good reputation ever end up with a question being put on hold!"_ They definitely do, it happens more rarely because, in general, they ask less questions and have more knowledge around what's an acceptable to post... which is the problem. If you're not finding out, _before_ posting, whether your question is appropriate then it might get put "on-hold"

Comment: If I asked an off-topic question, my question would be put on hold. (In fairness, I don't have a particularly high rep, but the rep I have wouldn't save me from myself.) In general, higher-rep users either (a) ask reasonable questions, or (b) don't ask many questions at all. If you look at mine you'll see that even *reasonable* questions got up and down voted--as retaliation.

Comment: I'm so sorry about the misunderstanding.
I had mentioned Stack Exchange sites as 'forum' which is incorrect.
The error is regretted and I've modified the question.

Comment: What does the number of votes of the following question imply? [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users)

Comment: That people think we should be nicer to new users. Notice that "nicer" does not mean "let them do whatever they want" or "do not subject them to the same standards as everyone else". We've had some problems with rudeness before. That's outright unacceptable. The user agreement requires that you *be nice* and treat others with basic human civility and respect.

Comment: "Don't be rude, offensive, snarky or unwelcoming" doesn't imply "lower your standards" @IndRaj95.

Comment: Also, note the date on that: 2008... The site is different and standards have changed in 5 years...!

Comment: There can be a better guide for new users on the sites.The meta site can release a pdf help file for download.

Comment: My question has lots of response only because it is in the meta site.
That is a key point to note.
For other questions there are not many comments and answers even if they are against the question because it becomes 'on hold', before that can happen.

Comment: Off topic questions get put "on hold" on Meta, too. There were just 4 of them in the last 10 minutes or so. I believe all have now been deleted. I guarantee if you ask good, on topic questions on SO, you'll get answers there, too.

Comment: *"There can be a better guide for new users on the sites"* .. have you taken a look at the About page or the Help Center recently? There are tons of information there. But if you find something seriously lacking, let us know. If it can be improved, such suggestions are always welcome.

Comment: "This question may already have an answer here: Can we have discussions? 1 answer"
@gnat
Its much more than that..I've asked about many things here unlike that question'...

Comment: Regarding this question,many questions can have a direct answer and broad answers can be easily avoided by smart answerers!
 [Broad questions not deemed fit for Q&A format](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189770/broad-questions-not-deemed-fit-for-qa-format)

Comment: It's up the the OP to ask a question that doesn't actually invite problematic answers.

Comment: Can I know what's meant by OP?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/what-does-op-mean

Comment: Give me the link to the original question which is exactly same as this question.
I have some suggestions and not all of them are duplicate.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because the answer here's better and it's now even more relevant because new contributors are now clearly identified.

Answer (score 18):

> I would like to request relaxing of moderation rules,to some extent,at least for new users,so that it will help new users like me in getting answers for their questions.

No it won't. Bad questions will not (or better, should not) receive answers.

> It will also enable us to learn more about the forums and understand the rules,on our own.

We have user help all over the place, you even have to agree that you read them when you first sign in (or post your first question), we can't do more then that. If you're diving head first into a community without knowing and/or reading their rules, you have to expect to be kicked out.

> Other forums,which I've seen,allow opinion and discussion.

Stack Exchange is not a forum...repeat after me, Stack Exchange is not a forum. It's a streamlined question and answer site/community. Discussion is, and hopefully always will be, off-topic.

> There can be a separate Stack Exchange site which can integrate all topics(it can be a site for many kind of 'off topic' questions) and it can also have moderators from various fields to keep an eye on it,based on the tags. It is difficult for everyone to find the best place to ask their questions,on their own.

This has been suggested multiple times in the past. The consensus is: If you want Yahoo! Answers, please go to Yahoo! Answers. Stack Exchange sites have a topic, stick to it.

> I feel these 'strict' rules keep the forum running in the long run and make moderation much easier.

Yes, exactly.

> If the question is from a new user,that's it! Its 'on hold' with the reason as 'off topic' or 'too broad' or something else.I don't think those with good reputation ever end up with a question being put on hold!

Having reputation is a result of writing good answers and/or questions which is a result of sticking to the rules. New users *love* to post something they *think* is appropriate, which is mostly not the case, there for the questions get closed.

> It should not be a condition that the user should know at least something about what he wishes to ask.

Excuse me? If we're talking about Stack Overflow/Server Fault then ***this is absolutely not acceptable***. Programmers should have an idea of what they're doing, if they don't know what they're doing they should start learning very fast or quit their job. Yes, this is a very hard opinion, but there's *a lot* of (economical) damage done by programmers who don't have the faintest idea of what they're doing.

For Super User not so much, yes.

> Questions are asked in forums basically to simplify the work to be done. If a person can search using search engines,all day long,to find an answer,then there would be no need for forums at all!!

If you can find the answer via search machines, then I have to ask you why ask the question in the first place? It obviously is already out there, ready to be found. If it needs *much* effort to be found, then it might be worthwhile to re-ask it on SE, as SE has a *much* higher visibility in search machines.

> I expect positive opinion from moderators and site administrators in this regard.

All of this has already been discussed in the past in one form or the other, it was all declined or not found to be useful.

Comment: I actually meant that search engines don't always do the work and that's the main reason there are questions in Q&A sites and forums.

Comment: New users will not always post questions that are bad or not worth answering.

Comment: @IndRaj95: Yes, your point is? (And if you now say that questions of new users get closed regardless of quality, I demand examples!)

Comment: I asked about how to go ahead with web hosting.I think it can have a direct answer without having to go for discussion or opinion.

Comment: @IndRaj95: Sounds opinion based, which is off-topic.

Comment: Steps or guidelines for web hosting..wat kind of opinion does it require?

Comment: @IndRaj95: [If we're talking about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788195/hosting-of-java-applications-as-packages-for-commercial-purpose), then it is off-topic. How you should sell your software *is* an opinion based question, even when you ask from a technical point of view. "Customizing the package as per the clients' needs and sending it to them" That's a question we cannot answer because we don't know the clients needs. "Releasing a licensed package which can be downloaded after payment" That describes pretty much *every* e-commerce system out there.

Answer (score 10):

> I would like to request relaxing of moderation rules,to some extent,at least for new users,so that it will help new users like me in getting answers for their questions.

No. Those rules are not in place to annoy new users. They are in place to maintain a certain level of quality on the site. Relaxing such rules would actively harm it. Yes, users have to dive in at the deep end, but if you do your best that should not be a hurdle that can't be overcome.

> Other forums,which I've seen,allow opinion and discussion.

Well, we're not other forums. We're not even a forum. We're a Q&A. And the site is so damn good precisely because we are one.

> There can be a separate Stack Exchange site which can integrate all topics(it can be a site for many kind of 'off topic' questions) and it can also have moderators from various fields to keep an eye on it,based on the tags.

That would only end up being some form of garbagedump.SE. We don't need to be an all-inclusive site. Nor an all-inclusive network. There are other sites for discussions, opinions, recommendations, tutorials, tutoring, or what have you. Use those instead if your questions don't fit within the network.

> It is difficult for everyone to find the best place to ask their questions,on their own.

Perhaps. So do your research. Read up on the site, what it is about, and then determine if your question is a good fit. You're not sure yet? Ask it on the site's Meta. They will tell you if it's a fit or not.

> Its 'on hold' with the reason as 'off topic' or 'too broad' or something else.I don't think those with good reputation ever end up with a question being put on hold!

That's nonsense. There might be a correlation. After all, the more experience you gain, the less likely you are to misunderstand the site's rules. But questions are not closed just because users are new. Nor do questions remain open because users have a lot of rep, if they are not a fit at all for the site.

> It should not be a condition that the user should know at least something about what he wishes to ask.Questions are asked in forums basically to simplify the work to be done. If a person can search using search engines,all day long,to find an answer,then there would be no need for forums at all!!

I don't directly care about the user's immediate problems. I care about good questions. And good question that have good answers. That is useful content beyond the OP's immediate concerns. That is what will stand the test of time. And once again, this is not a forum

As for your badge and moderator suggestions, I unfortunately don't know what you're getting at.

Comment: I just gave a name for it as golden badge.Its a kind of reward.

Moderators can post updates,which are not questions and which can be only read, and no comments or answers can be added.

Answer (score 9):

> I would like to request relaxing of moderation rules,to some extent,at least for new users,so that it will help new users like me in getting answers for their questions. It will also enable us to learn more about the forums and understand the rules,on our own.

How would relaxing the rules help anyone to learn? If the rules don't apply to you, you cannot learn them.

Moreover, this would have a detrimental effect on the community at large. We have rules and standards for a reason. If there was no reason for them, we wouldn't have them. Granting people a free pass to break the rules—for whatever reason—would serve no positive purpose.

We provide plenty of places for you to learn the rules, including the site help/FAQ page, the about page, and here on Meta. You can also ask questions on Meta about things you're unclear on. Then, of course, there's the "trial-by-fire" method where you do whatever you want and get your hand spanked if you broke the rules. Apparently this is the method you've been using. I can't say I recommend it, but it does "work"—you're learning what is and what is not acceptable, which is the whole point.

The only thing that might make sense is to be *forgiving* of new users who make mistakes when learning the rules. But of course, *we do that*! We don't allow them to continue making mistakes, but we don't hold it against them forever.

> Other forums,which I've seen,allow opinion and discussion.

Correct. This is what makes Stack Exchange sites different from other websites. [We do Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189770/broad-questions-not-deemed-fit-for-qa-format/189803#189803); we are not a forum, and we do not allow those things.

If you're seeking that, you already know where to go find it: somewhere other than here.

On the other hand, if you want good answers to technical questions without all the noise, you use us.

> There can be a separate Stack Exchange site which can integrate all topics(it can be a site for many kind of 'off topic' questions) and it can also have moderators from various fields to keep an eye on it,based on the tags. It is difficult for everyone to find the best place to ask their questions,on their own.

This has been suggested before, many times. I will never understand why it appeals to people. There are at least three problems:

1. Other websites like that already exist. Why should we duplicate them? Moreover, if they were so great, you'd be there, not here.
2. This type of site would just turn into an utter wasteland. Who would want to visit it? You certainly wouldn't have experts. You'd just have a bunch of clowns who didn't want to follow rules, didn't care about the community, and talked about nonsense. How would we know when that was a success? And who would clean up the garbage?
3. The whole Stack Exchange model simply doesn't work well for that type of site. That's why we have the rules that we do. Believe me, we've *tried* allowing "discussions" and relaxing the rules on what types of questions are permissible. The result was not pretty. Our rules and standards have evolved organically over the years. They're not there to frustrate you, they're there because that's the only way the site will work.

> If the question is from a new user,that's it! Its 'on hold' with the reason as 'off topic' or 'too broad' or something else.I don't think those with good reputation ever end up with a question being put on hold!

This is certainly incorrect. Questions are not put on hold based on the reputation or "new-ness" of the asker. Every question is evaluated independently, on its own merit. High reputation users have their questions closed sometimes, too. And new users with low reputation sometimes ask great questions that never get closed.

This observation simply conflates correlation with causality. New users *tend* to be the ones who ask questions that do not comply with our standards because they haven't taken the time to read them and haven't had enough experience to learn them other ways. Experienced users *tend* to know the rules better because they've been around longer and seen which types of questions get closed.

Besides, even if this *were* true, and all new users' questions were immediately put "on hold", I still can't see a big problem. The whole point of putting a question "on hold" is so that the asker can fix the problems that the community has identified with it and improve it to meet our standards. Once that happens, the question can and often *is* re-opened.

> It should not be a condition that the user should know at least something about what he wishes to ask.Questions are asked in forums basically to simplify the work to be done. If a person can search using search engines,all day long,to find an answer,then there would be no need for forums at all!!

There is a big difference between *knowing something* about what you want to ask, and *knowing the answer*. This is an extremely minimal bar that we're enforcing. You have to know *something* about the topic in order to ask a question about it. "I want to do x. Please write the code for me." is not a question. "I have written the following code, but it is not doing y. How can I fix it?" is a question. See the difference?

If you're looking for a place where you can get people to do work for you, you might be interested in http://www.freelancer.com/.

> - Questions and answers can have golden badge for most number of votes and most number of moderator votes and all golden badge questions can be grouped together.

Questions and answers already receive badges for votes. You can already sort questions by votes.

Aside from that, I fail to see how this would be a big improvement. You'd just create an "experts' corner" of Stack Overflow, which would just end up robbing yourself of expert advice—the whole reason you come here.

And even if that would be okay with you, it wouldn't be okay with me. Because although I am an expert in certain fields, I'm a complete novice in others. And that's not something weird about me, that pretty much describes everyone. This is why we don't have *complexity* or *difficulty* requirements for questions. No question is too basic, so long as it complies with our other standards. And like I've said several times, the standards are *quality*-related, not *difficulty*-related.

> - The moderators can also regularly keep posting updates and information related to their field which should be easily accessible to everyone.

First of all, moderators are not necessarily experts and they don't know everything. They certainly aren't experts in all topics. They're just regular community members who volunteer to help us to keep the site clean and in good working order.

There are lots of extremely smart people who contribute on the site that are *not* moderators. Those experts should be able to share their knowledge, too.

And, of course, they can! We just don't have a separate place on the site for it. That's what questions and tag wikis are for. If you have information to share, you are encouraged to [ask and answer your own question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). If you have general information about a specific topic that you think everyone should know, you can add it to the wiki for that topic's tag.

Comment: How do tag wikis exactly work?

Comment: [So what's this "tag wiki" thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57992)

Comment: The Ask&Answer should be appreciated.Its really a unique idea!!
Hats off to the team who found it!