# What does it mean when we say "be nice to new users"?

Tags: discussion, new-users

Today a brand new user to the SE community, asked a question about graph theory. This is the full text of their question

> Let G be a bipartite graph with 2n vertices exactly one perfect matching. Show that |E(G)| ≤(n+1). 2 Show that this bound is best possible for all n ∈ N≥1.

Moments later, an established Math SE user responded with the following:

> It appears that you are pasting your homework questions exactly, hoping to get someone here to provide you with the solution. If that is what you're doing, it is probably a violation of your school's academic integrity rules. If it's not what you are doing, you should explain in more detail what is actually going on and what kind of help you are looking for.

To recap: this was the new user's second post on the SE community, and because they clearly asked it without fully understanding the norms and cultural conventions of SE, they are being accused of violating academic integrity rules, downvoted into oblivion, and found their post summarily closed.

In the ensuing discussion, the new user wrote:

> I'm not an University student just want to have knowledge

In other words, they were self-studying, got stuck, and then tried asking for help on  a Q&A site.

So, what does it mean exactly to "be nice" to new contributors? I ask this because I see brand new users on the Math SE site who fail to properly dot all their i's and cross their t's encounter accusations, downvotes into oblivion, and (what I read as) hostility pretty much any time I passively browse the site.

I know that it's common for people to dump homework questions here with the expectation that others will do their work for them. But at the same time, it's probably more common that brand new users don't actually know the cultural norms of SE, don't know the ins and outs of the site, and find themselves genuinely confused to be met with accusations of academic integrity violations for asking a question in a Q&A community! It's no wonder that the vast majority of people I know don't consider Math SE to be a very inviting place to ask questions.

Anyway, it would seem that "be nice" should imply "assume good faith". What am I missing here?

With regard to the thread that some have suggested this is a duplicate of, I don't find them to be similar at all. This thread is specifically about new users, and in particular about assumptions of bad faith on the part of new users. The suggested thread does address some points about hostility to new users, but not really the point about bad faith. Further, it doesn't ask wheter assuming good faith should be part & parcel with "be nice".

Comment: The top-voted answer to [What about the community is "toxic" to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342779/what-about-the-community-is-toxic-to-new-users) addresses this question.

Comment: _"It's not my homework, I am asking for a friend ..."_

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog thanks for pointing that out. I don't think it does entirely -- I edited my post with why I feel that way, but let me know if you think I'm missing something in that post.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ you're insinuating bad faith based on literally nothing. We know exactly zero about rahul aside from what they've given us (a question that would be acceptable on most other Q&A sites on the internet, but doesn't meet SE standards), and a claim that they are just self-studying. It's one thing to point out that a post doesn't meet some standards. It's another to accuse someone of academic integrity violations. The latter basically guarantees we'll never see them again, regardless of reality.

Comment: [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189989/relaxation-of-rules-for-the-sites-and-other-suggestions) is also relevant.

Comment: "*Anyway, it would seem that "be nice" should imply "assume good faith".*" - They're certainly related, but don't always go hand in hand. I can assume good faith in that someone is asking legitimately for help, but be not nice in telling them their question is written awfully. The problem is not *necessarily* in the assumption of cheating, but in the way that's *communicated*. Sounds like there's also an element of ESL at play, at least from the asker's end.

Comment: consider [edit]ing your post to clarify why you state that this was _very first post_. Because as far as I can tell they asked at least one question [9 hours prior to one referred here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3937428/graph-theory-graph)

Comment: @gnat thanks for catching that. I missed that post when I first looked at their profile. It looks like it went similarly for rahul though

Comment: btw, @gnat that link is 404ing now

Comment: link says "This question was voluntarily removed by its author". I don't know why they decided to delete, although close banner suggested to improve this question. I also don't quite understand why you believe that second question was posted without fully understanding the rules while it appears to be posted 7 hours after the first question was closed with a large prominent banner at the top referring [Mathematics Stack Exchange guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: @Hugo You probably misunderstood my (hypothetical) cite. It's not about homework or not, and your critique regarding that comment on the OP's post you mentioned is legit (I am not so happy you're discussing and disclosing a concrete user here BTW). It should have been explained to them, that their question is too broad to be answered here, and what they should focus on. Down- and closevotres are about content quality, and / or lack of research, regardless if it's a homework or self-learning topic. There's nothing _"toxic"_ about that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Can you direct me towards a page or discussion about your point on discussing a concrete user? I don't mean to embarrass anyone or bring up their particular situation in a way that draws unwanted attention to them, and obviously I can see how the way I wrote my post may have been problematic in that way.

Comment: @Hugo _"Can you direct me towards a page or discussion about your point on discussing a concrete user? "_ Eeerm, you pointed at their profile in the second word of your post??

Comment: Yes... and I'm asking if you can point to anything where that's mentioned as a best practice and guidelines for these types of situations.

Comment: @Hugo Well, best practices gudes and from my guts and common sense say _**don't**_. How was that OPs profile relevant here?

Comment: This is solely about the culture of one specific site, and what the consider to be acceptable questions. Consider posting on the site specific meta instead.

Comment: Didn't realize there was one @Luuklag -- my mistake!

Comment: @Luuklag I beg to disagree, that's certainly a network wide topic.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ whilst copy-pasta comments are a network wide thing, I feel this has more to do with the high standard of questions Maths holds itself to, which is partly because of their (target) audience. These high standards make it that these sort of "textbook" questions are frowned upon, and hence met with these comments. Although the answers here are good as well.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I scrubbed the mention of the user and their post from mine. There are still references to them in the ensuing discussion unfortunately. Thanks for calling it out anyway

Comment: @Luuklag I think the same holds for high standards required at Stack Overflow, Physics, English Language and a number of other popular sites

Comment: Whenever I see 'Let', 'Consider' or 'Explain' at the top of an SO question, I am already 99% sure that a no-effort homework dump will follow.  Seems like Math is just as bad:(

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Some get paid through [Fiverr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiverr) and post others' homework assignments on Stack Exchange sites (and in most cases post it unchanged, without converting it into the Q&A format).

Comment: However, self study is more credible these days, with the [data science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_science) and [AI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence) craze. And new arbitrary HR filters that include advanced mathematics (even if it has *nothing* to do with the actual job).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65186892/758133. '3.  Consider.....'  I will be nice to newer users when they are nicer to me.  I start with respect, but that is too often gone by the time I get to the end of the title, never mind the homework section number and academic touchstone first word:(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65183528/758133 'Explain in detail' demand:(  Bonus deadbeat points for 'i++ + ++i', a pan-galactic gargle dupe that is in both the FAQ and tag wiki:((    If anyone wants to understand why niceness/respect drains away, this is a good example.

Comment: 'IT IS REALLY URGENT' command to the slave drones, https://stackoverflow.com/q/65183356/758133

Comment: 'Write a program...', complete with note from setter about the math library to use: 'https://stackoverflow.com/q/65182886/758133

Comment: I could keep that up all day, just dumping links to attempts to abuse and exploit SO contributors as assignment drones:(

Comment: So, I have to ask, WHERE IS THE NICE?

Answer (score 20):

> they are being accused of violating academic integrity rules

It takes a lot more to accuse someone. The specific quote here is:

> It appears that you are pasting your homework questions exactly, hoping to get someone here to provide you with the solution. If that is what you're doing, it is probably a violation of your school's academic integrity rules.

That's not accusing anyone, it's just stating that it *appears* like a homework dump, and *if* there is homework being dumped on the site, it *might* be a violation of academic integrity rules. **An accusation doesn't do if's and but's, an accusation would've been way more direct and straight to the point**: "you're violating academic integrity rules by dumping your homework on the site".

In short, it's not an accusation of violating academic integrity. What it is, is someone helpfully pointing out that the questions appears as if it *might* be though, which explains *why* Math.SE is likely to close and downvote such questions.

**Sometimes there just isn't a nicer way to say what must be said**: That some sites don't take homework dumps because of issues with quality and academic integrity violations. This comment leaves open the possibility that someone interpreted the nature of the question wrong, in which case an edit can improve it, as it points out as well.

All in all... it probably says what needs to be said, in as nice a manner as possible. Which is exactly what is meant with 'be nice to new users'.

Comment: It appears as if you are ignoring the crux of my question in order to perpetuate a culture of gatekeeping in STEM. If that is what you are doing, it's unfortunate. If it's not, well, you might want to fix that. Notice that I'm not accusing anyone, since I'm just stating how things appear and include a conditional to cover myself. 

Do you see how flimsy that is?

Comment: My point is that an accusation is an accusation, regardless of whether it's framed in between "It appears" and some conditional logic. In my mind there's too much fixation on an asker's motivations -- if we're truly here because we want to contribute to building a great Q&A/FAQ site, then why police the motivations of askers, especially when we have no insight into their lives other than what they provide on their SE profiles and in their Q&As, or, in the case of a new user, literally nothing? Why not simply respond to a poorly asked question with a link about how to ask qs on SE and move on?

Comment: @Hugo I've already used my answer to refute this being an accusation. I'm not going to allow you to waste my time on that point further. You've had the same explanation on Math.SE. You can keep misinterpreting a statement just so you can accuse other of accusing, it's not something I want to waste endless amounts of time and comments on. Assuming bad faith everywhere will get you nowhere.

Comment: The interpretation of this statement might be somewhat culturally dependent. If a Dutch person wanted to make an accusation, they'd be so direct and straight to the point. A British "accusation" would be much more indirect and hedgey. I don't know who's from where in the context of this question and commenter, but it's worth bearing in mind.

Comment: @Randal'Thor fair point. Still, Hugo was ready to quote the 'assume good faith' at the people they disagree with... which shows an amazing ability to 'assume good faith' on their part :) The good faith interpretation here is that it's just an explanation.

Comment: We're splitting hairs here. I don't think we should be making accusations or insinuations (or whatever you'd prefer to think of them as) of any kind towards newcomers, since by definition we don't know them. We can point them towards helpful resources about expections for question-asking on this site, and leave it at that. I don't see why the accusations/insinuations/whatever are even necessary because they're likely wrong anyway. Who benefits from them? Why does it make the site better for us to include them?

Comment: @Hugo One point of having explanations for close and down votes out in the open is that  new users browsing questions will also see these explanations, and know what *not* to do. The other people benefiting from comments explaining why a question should be closed are the people reviewing close votes in the queue.

Comment: But the fundamental issue isn't that the user might be violating academic integrity rules at their university -- it's that their question e.g. doesn't explain what they've attempted so far. It's entirely possible and within reason that the user in question was just self-studying (i.e. they weren't trying to cheat). So why not restrict our comments to what we know (the question was low quality) rather than suggest motives we really have no insight into? Note that these accusations/insinuations/whatever are public too, and associated to the user's account (which might use their real name).

Comment: @Hugo nice try. I repeat:  I've already used my answer to refute this being an accusation. I'm not going to allow you to waste my time on that point further. You've had the same explanation on Math.SE. You can keep misinterpreting a statement just so you can accuse other of accusing, it's not something I want to waste endless amounts of time and comments on. Assuming bad faith everywhere will get you nowhere.

Answer (score 9):

To some extent, we kind of expect a minimum level of effort from users

> Let G be a bipartite graph with 2n vertices exactly one perfect matching. Show that |E(G)| ≤(n+1). 2 Show that this bound is best possible for all n ∈ N≥1.

is *exactly* how it would be worded in a textbook. What OP has attempted isn't shown

> If it's not what you are doing, you should explain in more detail what is actually going on and what kind of help you are looking for.

Reflects that

> It appears that you are pasting your homework questions exactly, hoping to get someone here to provide you with the solution. If that is what you're doing, it is probably a violation of your school's academic integrity rules.

Is very true, and something that, on the balance of probability, worth stating.

> I'm not an University student just want to have knowledge – rahul 27 mins ago

Is nice but how is having a worked answer handed to them going to help, as compared to putting in that minimal effort in a question, showing where they are stuck, and being helped through *where* they are stuck? A good question helps the user learn more.

We need to be polite - but we also need to help folks help themselves by letting them know how they can better use the network. We *help* folks when we have material to work from, and help improve questions where there is *room* for improvement.

Comment: Can we simply direct them to some guidance on SE's quality standards for question-asking without accusing them of not having academic integrity? Whether or not it's the case that this is a student trying to get strangers to do their homework, accusing them of such doesn't really help anyone. In the best case, that is what is happening, and the student will apply serious effort towards learning the material and understanding the question. In the worst case, that isn't what's happening and you've someone off who simply didn't know the norms of the site before posting

Comment: Regardless, it's no one's job but their institution's to police their academic integrity. It certainly isn't your job or mine, given that we literally *know nothing about them*.

Comment: @Hugo - It’s certainly a legitimate reason for the community to NOT answer homework questions.  Asking for help from an unapproved source certainly was always mentioned as being not allowed in my college courses.  The author can certainly edit their question and it will be automatically sent to the queue to be reopened.  The question didn’t meet the minimum criteria for the community since that comment was submitted.